# 9 bit memory location - sign and magnitude

Tags: decimal, sign, negative-number

So I am trying to represent the number -256 in a 9 bit memory location using sign and magnitude.

Am I right in thinking that, there would be no representation for it?

For example, using +256 I don't see how a negative could fit in to what I have below:

```
+256 = 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
        1   0  0   0  0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm thinking that -256 would be too large for a 9-bit system?

Many thanks

Comment: I thought they stopped making 9-bit systems decades ago!

Comment: +256 is too big too, if your magnitude is only 8 bits.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the 256 column at the left

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I didn't fully understand your setup. I'll answer a bit "around".

If your "bit layout" is plain:

```
  9      8       7         6        5           1        0
sign rawvalue rawvalue rawvalue rawvalue ... rawvalue rawvalue
```

then with 1+8 bits you can have values:

```
-255 -254 ... -2 -1 -0 +0 +1 +2 ... +254 +255
```

since the edge cases are:

```
 111111111  ... 100000000 000000000 ... 011111111
   (-255)          (-0)     (+0)          (+255)
```

note that in such plain encoding there is **no such thing** as +256. It is +0. Of course you may work it around with some smart code, but at the base idea, it's actually +0 since the leftmost 1 felt into the "sign" bit and the rawvalue is 0.

Note that mathematically -0 == +0 but they have different signs. It's a waste of one value and also complicates the mathematical operations. This was one amongst other reasons for the **two-complement** system to be introduced, that would allow you to use values in range of

```
   -256    ...    -2        -1         0        +1        +2     ...   +255
100000000 ... 111111110 111111111 000000000 000000001 000000010 ... 011111111
```

In two's complement system, the first bit is also called the "sign bit", but the negative numbers are wisely encoded instead of just being "sign=1" followed by "rawvalue". Here, negative values are "inverted". Such encoding allows very easy mathematical operations, since i.e:

```
  0 - 1 ==> 0  ===>   000000000 - 000000001 ==> 111111111 +underflow,ignored
 -1 + 1 ==> 0  ===>   111111111 + 000000001 ==> 000000000 +overflow,ignored
```

So, depending on the encoding you've chosen, you will never have +256, but you might have -256 available (two's complement), or not (plain sign).

(btw, taking plain and twoscomplement aside: Of course, you may take any other encoding or encode the number in any way you want, ie. to have range of -11..500 or something like that, but then probably there won't be any obvious "sign" bit there)

Answer (score 0):

**-256 cannot be represented using this method.** To represent the magnitude 256 and above you need 9 bits. This leaves no room for a sign bit.

You can represent the magnitudes **0 to 255** inclusive along with a sign bit using this method.

If you wanted to represent -256 to 255 inclusive then use [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).